# Trying to assign a string result from a query into a trigger's string variable

Tags: trigger, soql

I'm trying to assign a string result from a query into a trigger's string variable, and this is the error I receive:

Compile Error: Illegal assignment from LIST to String at line 42 column 12

```
string SEMCODE;

// Most Recent SEM Code
SEMCODE = [select SEM_Code__c from Interaction__c where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c
           ORDER BY Start_Date_Time__c Desc Limit 1];
```

How can I get the SEM_Code__c value from the single record query result?

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the error message was that you were assigning a List into string variable, which the system will not allow. You can do something like this:

```
 string SEMCODE;
 SEMCODE = [SELECT SEM_Code_c 
            FROM Interaction_c 
            WHERE Contact_c = :record.Contact_c 
            ORDER BY Start_Date_Time__c DESC LIMIT 1].SEM_Code__c;
```

You can find more information about this [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex/Content/langCon_apex_SOQL_single_row.htm):

Comment: Thanks theGreatDanton, it compiled, now to finish this thing!

Comment: @KevinRussell Do you also understand why this works and what you were doing wrong ?

Comment: Not exactly, but I imagine the query is a query object and the .SEM_Code__C is how to access the field property....  It did work for me in my trigger.