# List query results into a string

Tags: apex, list

I have a requirement that I need to display all Account Team Members for a specific Account in a text field for reporting. using [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23767/trying-to-assign-a-string-result-from-a-query-into-a-triggers-string-variable) post as a guide, I can a list of the results but I cannot figure out how to takes the result and convert it to a string that I can put into the field. I started working in the dev console so I can test out the syntax quickly. Example:

```
Set<ID> accId = new Set<Id>();
accId.add('001A000001LFBFT');
String dan =[SELECT User__r.FirstName,
                    User__r.LastName
             FROM NPD_Account_Team__c
             WHERE Account__c IN :accId
             ORDER BY User__r.FirstName DESC].User__r.FirstName;
System.debug('dan is:: ' + dan);
```

This compiles but when run it gives the error:

> List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject.

Ideally what I want to happen is that if I have Account Team members as:
Tom
Dick
Harry

I would have a string that would say 'Dick, Harry, Tom'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have more that one potential record you cannot access the fields without providing an index. Doing it blindly as such is **not advisable** and will only get the first record anyway.

```
[SELECT User__r.FirstName,
                        User__r.LastName
                 FROM NPD_Account_Team__c
                 WHERE Account__c IN :accId
                 ORDER BY User__r.FirstName DESC][0].User__r.FirstName
```

You should iterate over the records and add them to the string as such:

```
Set<ID> accId = new Set<Id>();

//Populate accId with values

Map<Id,Set<String>> accountMap = New Map<Id,Set<String>>(); //Ensures no duplicates

for(NPD_Account_Team__c aTeam : [SELECT User__r.FirstName,
                    User__r.LastName
             FROM NPD_Account_Team__c
             WHERE Account__c IN :accId
             ORDER BY User__r.FirstName DESC]){

        Set<String> userSet = accountMap.get(aTeam.Account__c);
        if(userSet == null) userSet = New Set<String>();
        userSet.add(aTeam.User__r.FirstName);
        accountMap.put(aTeam.Account__c,userSet);
     }
    System.debug('usersString is:: ' + string.join(New List<String>(usersSet),','); //Need to convert to list before joining
}

Account[] accTBU = New Account[]{};

for(Id aId : accountMap.keySet()){
     accTBU.add(
         New Account(
                Id=aId,
                USERFIELD = string.join(
                                New List<String>(accountMap.get(aId)),
                                ','
                             )
     );
}

update accTBU;
```

Comment: Does the Set automatically detects duplicates or is needed by calling the `contains()` method?

Comment: @MartinLezer - A set is unique values by definition. If you have ["A"] and do set.add("A") you will be left with ["A"]. the only drawback it you have to convert to a list before joining. Of course if the OP want "Fred,Fred,Fred" then don't use set

Comment: Omg. I'm using the Set class wrong for 2 years.... I was thinking that the `contains` method was useful to verify that the Set doesn't contain a value before adding it...

Comment: @MartinLezer - Map keys obviously work the same `Map<String,String>` having {"A" : "B"} and `put("A", "C");` will be left with {"A" : "C"}.

Comment: Yes now you say it, that's obvious. I knew it for the Map. But I never made the link with the keys used as a `Set` class.

Comment: How would you go back and then update the Account Ids that were passed over from the Set?

Comment: @DanWooding - I would probably put the Set<string> in a map with the Account ID as a Key. Then when time to update, construct a New account for each key, setting the Id and Field for the strings, then do a DML update

Comment: Is it possible you can give an example of that?

Comment: @DanWooding - I roughly updated the answer. Proper debugging may be required

Answer (score 8):

For this you will need to loop over the multiple records returned by the query. One way to do that is:

```
String[] names = new String[] {};
for (NPD_Account_Team__c t : [
        SELECT User__r.FirstName, User__r.LastName
        FROM NPD_Account_Team__c
        WHERE Account__c IN :accId
        ORDER BY User__r.FirstName DESC
        ]) {
    names.add(t.User__r.FirstName);
}

String s = String.join(names, ', ');
```

Comment: Nice solution ! :D

Comment: @MartinLezer Looks like we agree...

Comment: I prefer our solution than @Eric's. :D

Comment: @MartinLezer - Ha, I was in middle of editing, pasted placeholder code while I updated lol - Needed to change it to set to remove duplicates

Answer (score 3):

Here's the best solution I could think of:

```
Set<ID> accId = new Set<Id>();
accId.add('001A000001LFBFT');
List<String> accountNames = List<String>();
for(NPD_Account_Team__c account : [SELECT User__r.FirstName,User__r.LastName FROM NPD_Account_Team__c WHERE Account__c IN :accId ORDER BY User__r.FirstName DESC]){
   accountNames.add(account.User__r.FirstName);
}
System.debug(accountNames.join(','));
```

As you can see, first, you have to query all the accounts to store their first names in an array.

Then, you call the join function of the array.